Should the IDL definition of a callback throw an error if the return type does not match?
There is such a definition of IDL:

callback NavigationInterceptHandler = Promise<undefined> ();

This corresponds to the property of the handler argument passed to the intercept method of the navigate event:
navigation.addEventListener('navigate', (event) => {
    event.intercept({handler(){
      /// For corresponding with return type of IDL
      return Promise.resolve(undefined);
    }});
  });

The question is: should an error occur if the return type is other than Promise, and if the result is a Promise, but its result is not undefined, should an error occur?
As another example, consider this IDL:

callback FrameRequestCallback = undefined (DOMHighResTimeStamp time);

This corresponds to the callback argument in the requestAnimationFrame function:
requestAnimationFrame(function(){
  /// For corresponding with return type of IDL
  return undefined;
})

What happens if in this case we return a value other than undefined? Does this break the interface? Should this throw an error?
I tried to find information about return value matching, but WebIDL doesn't seem to say anything like that. If I missed anything let me know.
If in both cases we return inappropriate value types, then no errors will occur, why?

The return_type of the callback function does not represent what the JS function must or should return. Instead it's what the IDL callback function itself will return.
In invoke a callback function you can see that in the step 13, if everything went well, callResult.[[Value]] (the value returned by your JS function) is converted "to the IDL value of the same type as [the IDL callback function] callable’s return type.". So you as an author don't have to ensure the return value of your JS function will match with this signature, the IDL side will take care of it.
Might be noted that in case of an abrupt completion (i.e. something did throw while calling the JS callback), even that abrupt completion might be converted to a rejected Promise in case the callback function's return type is a Promise.

Do I understand correctly that if we take attribute object? valueAsDate (IDL of input). If we write inputEl.valueAsDate in the code, then first the conversion from IDL to javascript will occur, and then the getter algorithm will be executed. And if we write inputEl.valueAsDate = 5, then first there will be a conversion from javascript to IDL (where an error will occur based on the attribute type in this case), and then execution of the setter algorithm. Right?

That's not really related to callback functions. "then first the conversion from IDL to javascript will occur, and then the getter algorithm will be executed." no, there is nothing before the getter steps are executed. Only the return value of the getter steps will be converted to a JS value. As for the setter steps, yes the conversion of the input is done before.

Oh sure, you noticed my mistake in relation of the getter side, you're absolutely right. Thanks, for the clarification.
